# Laravel subdomain routing redirect to 404 if route not in subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, routes, subdomain

I am using subdomain routing in my app and will like for requests to subdomain routes to be redirected to a 404 page if the requested route does not exists in the subdomain. Here is the scenario:

```php
// Subdomain routes
Route::domain('app.mysite.test')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){
        dd("Home page for subdomain");
    });

    Route::get('/404', function(){
        dd("Subdomain 404");
    });
    //... other subdomain routes here
});

// Top domain routes
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Site'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){
        dd("Main site home page");
    });

    Route::get('/login', function(){
        dd("Main site LOGIN page");
    });
});
```

In the above scenario, if someone tries to access a route that does not exist in the subdomain (eg `http://app.mysite.test/login`), they will be automatically redirected to the login page of the main site (ie: `http://mysite.test/login`).

My question is: How to I redirect users to `http://app.mysite.test/404` if they try to access `http://app.mysite.test/login`?

Comment: The question is *why* would they be redirected to `mysite.test/login` to begin with? It's not the default behaviour and nothing in the code you shared here is meant to do this

Comment: I believe that is the default behavoir, which is why the documentation says your subdomain routes should be placed above the main domain routes. So if a request does not match any route in the subdomain, it renders the route from the main domain if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution: At the end of the Subddomain route group, add a `catchall` expression that basically catches everything that's not in the subdomain routes and renders the 404 page. Make sure this `catchall` route is at the end of your subdomain routes:

```php
// Subdomain routes
Route::domain('app.mysite.test')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){
        dd("Home page for subdomain");
    });

    //Route::get('/404', function(){
    //    dd("Subdomain 404");
    //});
    //... other subdomain routes here

    // ADD THE CATCHALL REGEX HERE
    Route::get("{catchall}", function(){
        dd("404 page from subdomain");
    })->where('catchall', '(.*)');
});

// Top domain routes
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Site'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){
        dd("Main site home page");
    });

    Route::get('/login', function(){
        dd("Main site LOGIN page");
    });
});
```